# Написал код для еххо бота в телеграме подключил aiogram а бот при старте выбивает ошибка синтаксиса

Tags: python, aiogram

```
from aiogram import bot, Dispatcher, executor, types


TOKEN_API 5815088766:AAFah-YHZf0-grAWb5eY0RwAn6LwBQzjGy0

bot = BOT(TOKEN_API)
dp = dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message.handler()
async def echo(massage: type.massange):                  
    await message.answer(text=massage.text)

if __name__=='__main__':
               executer.start_poling(dp)
```

Comment: Не показывайте никому свой токен. А так то правильный синтаксис `TOKEN_API = токен`, знак присваивания потеряли.

Comment: И сам токен нужно обернуть в кавычки.

Answer (score 4):

Понятно, у вас ошибка синтаксиса:

```
  File "...", line 4
    TOKEN_API 5815088766:AAFah-YHZf0-grAWb5eY0RwAn6LwBQzjGy0
              ^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Наверное у вас код должен быть таким:

```py
from aiogram import bot, Dispatcher, executor, types


TOKEN_API = "ваш токен"

bot = BOT(TOKEN_API)
dp = dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message.handler()
async def echo(massage: type.massange):                  
    await message.answer(text=massage.text)


if __name__=='__main__':
    executer.start_poling(dp)
```